# Assigning a new variable based on date

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to create a new time variable that assigns how many months have passed since the first date for every ID

For example

```
ID      Date      
aa1    4/1/2015    
aa1    10/1/2015    
aa1    4/1/2016    
aa1    7/1/2015   
aa1    1/1/2016    
aa1    1/1/2015    
aa2n   4/1/2017    
aa2n   10/1/2017    
aa2n   10/1/2016   
aa2n   1/1/2017   
aa2n   7/1/2017
```

I would like to output to be

```
 ID      Date      Time
aa1    1/1/2015     0
aa1    4/1/2015     3
aa1    7/1/2015     6 
aa1    10/1/2015    9
aa1    1/1/2016     12
aa1    4/1/2016     15
aa2n   10/1/2016    0
aa2n   1/1/2017     3
aa2n   4/1/2017     6 
aa2n   7/1/2017     9
aa2n   10/1/2017    12
```

The Date variable is by quarters so the earliest quarter is 0 and each subsequent quarter is +3

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `lubridate` + `tidyverse` solution

```
library(lubridate);
library(tidyverse);
df %>%
    mutate(Date = mdy(Date)) %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(Time = month(Date) - month(min(Date)) + 12 * (year(Date) - year(min(Date)))) %>%
    arrange(ID, Time)
## A tibble: 11 x 3
## Groups:   ID [2]
#   ID    Date        Time
#   <fct> <date>     <dbl>
# 1 aa1   2015-01-01    0.
# 2 aa1   2015-04-01    3.
# 3 aa1   2015-07-01    6.
# 4 aa1   2015-10-01    9.
# 5 aa1   2016-01-01   12.
# 6 aa1   2016-04-01   15.
# 7 aa2n  2016-10-01    0.
# 8 aa2n  2017-01-01    3.
# 9 aa2n  2017-04-01    6.
#10 aa2n  2017-07-01    9.
#11 aa2n  2017-10-01   12.
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "ID      Date
aa1    4/1/2015
aa1    10/1/2015
aa1    4/1/2016
aa1    7/1/2015
aa1    1/1/2016
aa1    1/1/2015
aa2n   4/1/2017
aa2n   10/1/2017
aa2n   10/1/2016
aa2n   1/1/2017
aa2n   7/1/2017    ", header = T)
```

Comment: Thank you this worked, if possible could you explain the second mutate line?

Comment: @Al.So The second `mutate` line calculates the difference in months as `diff(month, first_month_in_group) + 12 * diff(year, first_year_in_group)`, where the last term ensures that we correctly count the number of months passed for the case where more than a year has passed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it: 
You might need to convert your date from the format you have to the format of the "date" column below.

```
library(zoo)
df <- data.frame(ID = c("aa1", "aa1", "aa1", "aa1"),
             Date = as.Date(c("4/1/2015", "10/1/2015", "4/1/2016", "7/1/2015")),
             date = as.Date(c("2015-04-01", "2015-10-01", "2016-04-01", "2015-07-01")))

df$time <- format(as.yearqtr(df$date, format = "%m/%d/%Y"), format = "%q")
```

Comment: This would set the first quarter as 1, the second as 2, etc and then for the next year the first quarter is back to 1, no?

Comment: Ah yes, then you can do this: 

`library(zoo)
df <- data.frame(ID = c("aa1", "aa1", "aa1", "aa1"),
                 Date = as.Date(c("4/1/2015", "10/1/2015", "4/1/2016", "7/1/2015")),
                 date = as.Date(c("2015-04-01", "2015-10-01", "2016-04-01", "2015-07-01"))) %>% 
  mutate(time = as.numeric(format(as.yearqtr(df$date, format = "%m/%d/%Y"), format = "%q"))) %>% 
  mutate(time = time - 1)`